# Как принудительно заставить не удалять класс при линковке?

Tags: android, отладка, xamarin, компоновщик

Как принудительно заставить не удалять класс при линковке?
Пишу приложение под Android в Visual Studio 2015 на фреймворке Xamarin. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: приложение замечательно работает в режите **Debug**, а вот когда ставлю режим **Release** часть функционала приложения теряется, т.е. несколько классов удаляюся при линковке и при их вызове приложение крашется.
Пробовал как написано в документации Xamarin ставить перед классом один из атрибутов:

```
[Android.Runtime.Preserve]
[Android.Runtime.Preserve (AllMembers = true)]
[Android.Runtime.Preserve (Conditional = true)]
```

не помогло. Пробовал также:

```
#pragma warning disable 0219, 0649
```

тоже не помогло. Пробовал также использовать **linkskip**, но тоже не помогло.

Единственное решение, которое пока нашел, так это в свойствах линкера указать **Linker Behavior = Don't Link (None in Visual Studio)** (как в режиме **Debug**). Но это плохое решение, т.к. подходит для отладки, но не для релиза. И размер приложения увеличился более чем в 2.5 раза!

Comment: что мешает перейти на Android Studio?

Comment: после c# на java вообще писать не хочется.